# SQL server db design - partition key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which is a better option?

1. Both columns as primary key (with clustered index):

`column_id, partition_key_id`

or

2. `column_id` (primary key nonclustered index), `partition_key_id` (clustered index)

Thank you for the answers

Comment: Impossible to answer without any context about how you judge "better". But the 2 suggestions are very different and will not support the same type of uniqueness, so perhaps you should focus on what the primary key should be first - and the decide on the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

For performance the correct response is: “It is depends on your queries”

Below 10 best practice tips that could help you:

1. Only partition where goals / benefits clear
2. Choose suitable partition column used in most queries
3. Always leave empty partition at start / end of ranges (or pre-size it!)
4. Beware impacts to PK, UK and FK for partition column
5. Use different FG’s for different partitions (for backup/restore)
6. Keep regularly joined tables in same partition range and FG’s
7. Don’t share partition function/scheme across objects (SPLIT impact)
8. If using SWITCH (for load/archive) then partition align all indexes
9. Only rebuild fragmented partitions, not full index
10. Use MAXDOP, SORT_IN_TEMPDB, ONLINE as much as possible

As regards the operation, you are getting different unique keys.

In the first example, uniqueness is on column_id, partition_key_id.

In the second example, uniqueness is only on column_id.